# Business card offset printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I designed my business card in illustrator (3.5" x 2"), my colors are CMYK process colors, someone told me I should separate the colors before sending it to the printer, is that right? or that is the print house problem not mine, so all in all does offset printing for a business card needs color separation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I stand by my answer but I will explain more.

#### You need to check if they do not mean to assign the colors as spot colors.

In Spanish, We have two clear distinct terms. Color separation and color selection, and they are not the same. See if they are not using the concept in a similar way.

If your logo is Red, a color selection will transform this color to some magenta and yellow and mix them together again when printing.

A color separation is when you assign your logo with pure red as spot color, for example, a Pantone Red 032 C.

Here are two examples, a "full-color" logo and one with only two colors.

In the first example, it is ok if the logo gets separated into CMYK components.

But in the second one, it is probably better to send the image as spot colors

[image]

Traditionally the process was totally different. For a color photography, you needed to screen it using 4 different filters. For a spot ink, you simply took the picture of the original.

Sometimes you used the exact same negative and "painted" in top of it, blocking some parts and leaving other parts visible. They were manually separated.

Now, of course, the process is different, and it is pretty obvious that the colors are "separated" when making the plates. But that part is just an automatic process. **But what values you need to send to each plate, any plate, C, M, Y, K or a golden metallic ink, varnish or whatever, is a design decision.**

Here is another example of how you can handle different plates for different projects.

[image]

Comment: *"A color separation is when you assign your logo with pure red as spot color"* this is **completely** incorrect. [Color separations](https://www.thoughtco.com/color-separation-1697622) is the process of splitting colors into CMY and K plates for reproduction. And *clearly* that's what the question is asking about.

Comment: @Scott No. Rafael is correct. This what pre-press handles. But we do still call it CMYK color separation. Ex: Changing text from CMYK black to just K.

Comment: Spanish terminology could be a little different but the idea is still correct. It might help if you had a non-spanish picture

Comment: Hey join us in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot

Comment: Rafael I wanted to suggest an edit for you to replace that image with this one. https://i.stack.imgur.com/egKTy.jpg

Comment: I'll concede that maybe it's a language thing. In the US.. changing a Processes color to a spot color is *never* called "separation" in any form. I have *never* run into a situation where there was confusion over what "color separation" meant.

Comment: Edit is decent. I don't mean to question your knowledge in any  way. I just think this is completely off topic as to what the user is asking. It's standard, at least here,  for the *designer* to choose colors and *how* those colors will be printed (spot or process). It's almost *never* the print providers choice as to what color gets printed. At most a print provider may suggest a spot color when that would yield better results. But it's rare the print provider is choosing WHICH colors are used.

Comment: Exactly that is the point. Choosing the color, the process, the ink, is a design decision. Not the printer's choice. The user said "someone told me" it does not say "the printer is forcing me" n_n

Comment: But the user also specifically states "CMYK" that's why I think this is all is kind of ultimately more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Choosing, specifying, stipulating, etc. colour are artistic and aesthetic considerations. Colour separations are a photo-mechanical process for producing printing industry standard 4C process printing plates using screening. A Raster Image Processor breaks down or separates the composite computer image into discrete mono-colour printing plates. Scott's answer is correct. Raphael's leading bold face statement is confusing and confused.

Answer (score 4):

*Everything* which is offset printed requires color separations. That's simply how offset printing works.

However, color separations are the job of the print house. It is their area of expertise.

A designer should merely need to provide a valid PDF/X-1a file set up to the proper dimensions.

As *always*, if you are uncertain what your print provider will need... ask them! They are always willing to help with information.

Comment: _A designer should merely need to provide a valid PDF/X-1a file_ —Is that absolutely required in most cases? PDF/X-3 or 4 won't do?

Comment: I would say that nowdays PDF/X-4 would be much more better idea. And yes, no sepatation is needed from your side, repro inhouse will do that for particular printing press.

Comment: X3 or X4 are fine.. I think X1 is often the most error proof if you aren't familiar with the print provider though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're not doing this with a digital printer but...

## Yes, you do need to separate the colors unless you want to pay for 4 colors when your job only has 2 or 3 colors.

Even if you decide to go with 4 colors you need to assign the black as 100% black or your CMYK business card will make the black out of CMYK.
[image]

[image]